# why doesn't this "if"-statement work?

Tags: c++, pointers, if-statement

```
bool foo( int* p )
{
  return false;
}

int* bar (  )
{
  int* p;
  return p;
}

int main() {

  if ( int* p = bar() && foo( p ) )
  //if ( ((int* p = bar()) != NULL ) && (foo( p )) ) // another variant
  {

  }

  return 0;
}
```

I get `error: cannot convert ‘bool’ to ‘int*’ in initialization` with GCC 4.3.4 and VS 2008. If there is only `if ( int* p = bar())` everything works fine.

I know i can initialize `p` before `if`-statement, but i'm interested in the variant i shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of an `if` requires a *condition* in the parentheses.  A
condition can be either an expression, or a declaration (of a
type with an implicit conversion to `bool`); it cannot be a combination
of these.  In the case of

```
if ( int* p = bar() && foo( p ) )
```

, the *condition* is "`int* p = bar() && foo( p )`", which is a simple
declaration of a type `int*` initialized with `bar() && foo( p )`; since
the type of `bar() && foo( p )` isn't `int*`, and can't be implicitly
converted into an `int*`, you have an error.

If you write:

```
if ( (int* p = bar()) != NULL )
```

, the opening parentheses mean that this cannot be a declaration (simple
or no), and `int* p = bar()` isn't a legal (sub-)expression.

The critical point to remember is that you can have a declaration, *or*
you can have an expression, but that you can't combine them, and the C++
doesn't allow declarations as part of an expression.  (Also: the
declaration must have copy initialization:

```
if ( int* p = bar() )
```

, direct initialization is not allowed.)

Answer (score 4):

```
int* p = bar() && foo( p )
```

first evaluates logic expression, then assigns

the same as writing:

```
int *p = ( bar() && foo(p) );
```

Comment: @forgbit: I would prefere `if ( bar() && foo() ) {}`. Remember that simple is better than complex

Comment: I would too, but what if you're giving with a framework like i shown? When you have to pass the result of the first function as input param to the second one?

Comment: @fogbit: I would create a local variable for that purpose

Answer (score 3):

Assignment operator `=` has a lower priority than boolean and `&&` thus what you have is this:

```
int* p = ( bar () && foo(p) )
```

which is an attempt to assign a `bool` to an `int*` variable.

**Edit**: While it's generally an accepted practice to declare and init variables in the loop's block (like `for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)`) I would strongly advise against such a construct for conditional statements, like `if()` as it could lead to some very fascinating side-effects that you really don't want to deal with as well as reduce the readability of your code.

Your other variant should work (except I'm not sure you want to compare the result of declaraion `int*...` to a NULL - that may not be liked by the language), but see my comment above about **code clarity**

Comment: What about "another variant" i placed in the code? Could you tell why doesn't it work?

Comment: Avoid declaring variables in the `if()` statement and you should be fine :)

Comment: Could you show an example of the side-effects? And my other variant doesn't work, i get ``error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'p'`` in VS2008 and similar error in GCC. Could you tell the compiller you use, please?

Comment: There's no assignment operator in his example (or yours).

Comment: @YePhIcK: this is the point to have a variable declared in ``if``, because i don't need this variable outside the statement. And, in my opinion, adding two additional ``{}`` makes the code less readble.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
bool foo( int* p )
{
  return false;
}

int* bar (  )
{
  int* p;
  return p;
}

int main() {
  int* p;
  if ( (p = bar()) && foo( p ) )
  //if ( ((int* p = bar()) != NULL ) && (foo( p )) ) // another variant
  {

  }

  return 0;
}
```

OR

```
int main() {

  if ( int* p = bar()){
      if ( foo( p ) ){ /*do something*/ }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

it runs

Comment: I did and i got ``error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'p'`` in VS2008

Comment: this works, inspite this is not exactly what i'd like to have, thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

The condition of an `if` statement can be *either* a declaration *or* an expression. A declaration isn't an expression, so you can't combine it with another expression as you are trying to do. In other words, while you were hoping for

```
(int* p = bar()) && foo(p)
```

this isn't valid, since `int* p = bar()` isn't an expression. Instead it is read as the declaration

```
int* p = (bar() && foo(p))
```

which isn't valid because the initialiser has the wrong type.

In this case, you're going to have to declare the pointer before the `if` statement; a couple of options are:

```
int* p = bar(); // pollutes surrounding scope; maybe wrap in another block
if (p && foo(p)) {}

if (int* p = bar()) {
    if (foo(p)) {  // extra nesting
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is the operator precedence. You in fact execute:

```
if ( int* p = (bar() && foo( p )) )
```

But what you mean to execute, I believe is:

```
if ( (int* p = bar()) && foo( p ) )
```

Which is not exactly the same.

Answer (score -1):

The fact is that you are making an assignment with `int* p = bar()` and the statement tries to compare two types: `int` and `bool`, and that is not possible.

You should assign it before the IF statement.

Hope this helps